# How to import the native characters like(ধামুরা বন্দর) from Json to SQL using Openrowset bulk option

Tags: json, unicode, openrowset

Am trying to import data from Json to Sql server. The file is in UTF-8 format and there are native characters like (ধামুরা বন্দর). When i use Openrowset with bulk option by passing the file, am getting the value as à¦¬à¦¿ à¦ à¦à¦« à¦¶à¦¾à¦–à¦¾, à¦¢à¦¾à¦•à¦¾

### Code

Declare @KettleFeed Varchar(MAX)

Select @KettleFeed=
BulkColumn
from OPENROWSET(Bulk 'D:\Json_Samples\Test.json',SINGLE_BLOB) Json

```
    Select * from 
    OpenJson(@KettleFeed,'$')
    With(
        NativeName Nvarchar(100) N'$.NativeName'
    )
```

If i want to use SINGLE_NCLOB then file should be in Unicode format which am not able to do in Notepad++. Not sure how we can do it.

If i use the Json directly by prefixing N, instead of file like the below am getting the output. My question is how to use when we are using file.

Declare @Json nvarchar(Max)
Set @Json=
N'{
"Version":"2",
"Name":"V-#$$&((*&*^&&%$Bhaskar",
"NativeName":"ধামুরা বন্দর"
}'

Output is as expected.

Version:2,
Name:V-#$$&((*&*^&&%$Bhaskar
NativeName":"ধামুরা বন্দর

Any idea on how to fix it

Comment: Specify [`CODEPAGE = '65001'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#bulk-input-file-format-options) option?

Comment: Hi Jose, I used Select @KettleFeed=
 BulkColumn
 from OPENROWSET(Bulk N'D:\Json_Samples\Test.json',SINGLE_NCLOB,CODEPAGE = '65001') Json  and its throwing below error as                                                                           
        SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode.  Even if i dont use Codepage am getting the same error